# Visual studio and xamarin using c# releasing on mobile?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mobile, xamarin, release

I am making an android application using visual studio and xamarin using the c# language but when i copy the apk file to the mobile and after installing it doesn't open and give me the message: " unfortunately your app has been stopped " what can i do please i need to open it on mobile?

Comment: Why dont you plug your device in and build it straight to the device?

Comment: Can you be more specific what to do?@user1

Comment: Have you tried: Deploying it directly from the IDE and using the debugger to find out what's wrong?  Checking the device logs?

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging_with_xamarin_android/

Comment: How can i release it on my samsung mobile ??

Comment: read the docs: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you also need the mono runtime and all the support libraries that are needed.

Run your app once from the debugger (or at least deploy from within Visual Studio/Xamarin Studio), and you will

a) get a notice (in deploy output) about all the libraries/frameworks being installed before the app launches, this can actually take a minute before first launch

b) you have those supports installed for the future, so as long as you target the same framework version, you can simply directly install the .apks

Normally, you don't use .apks directly, since most often your first shot is not perfect anyway, so the debugging helps a lot. :)